# How to create a Map with immutable keys and no duplicates using Google Guava?

Tags: java, guava

I'd like to create a key/value map structure using Google Guava where the keys cannot be modified but the values can.  I also want the ability to use a predicate (or something similar) to iterate the Map and only retrieve those entries that have values.

For example, conceptually:

```
// start
Map data =
{Constants.KEY_NAME_1, Optional.absent()},
{Constants.KEY_NAME_2, Optional.absent()};

// succeeds
data.put(Constants.KEY_NAME_2, Optional.of("new_data"));

// finish
Map data =
{Constants.KEY_NAME_1, Optional.absent()},
{Constants.KEY_NAME_2, Optional("new_data")};

// fails
data.put(Constants.KEY_NAME_3, Optional.of("more_new_data"));
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

-------- Solution --------

As per the comments below, I went with the ForwardingMap.  The Implementation is straightforward

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ForwardingMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList;
import java.util.Map;

Map<String, String> labelMap = ImmutableMap.<String, String> builder()
    .put("KEY_1", "data1")
    .put("KEY_2", "data2")
    .build();

MyCustomMap<String> map = new MyCustomMap(labelMap);

public class MyCustomMap<String> extends ForwardingMap<String, String> {

    private final Map<String, String> delegate;
    private final ImmutableMap<String, String> immutableMap;

    public MyCustomMap(Map<String, String> labelMap) {

        /*
            Check for duplicate values in the map here.  The construction of 
            the ImmutableMap above ensures that there are no duplicate
            keys.  Otherwise it will throw
            "IllegalArgumentException: Multiple entries with same key".
        */

        delegate = labelMap;
        immutableMap = ImmutableMap.<String, String>builder().putAll(delegate).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> delegate() {
        return immutableMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I fail to understand why the last line would fail. What don't you tell?

Comment: Because KEY_NAME_3 does not already exist in the map.  When the attempt is made to put it in, a failure occurs.

Comment: Then see my answer; what you want is to use a `ForwardingMap`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guava cannot do anything for you if your keys are not immutable; this is something you have to ensure yourself (by making sure that the class of all keys is an immutable class).

Even an `ImmutableMap` is not immune to this kind of mishap:

```
// Modify the key
victim.keySet().iterator().next().alterMe();
```

If what you wish to do is customize the behavior upon insertion/retrieval then you can use a [`ForwardingMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html) to wrap another `Map` instance.

Beware however that this class leaves you a lot of freedom, including that of breaking the `Map` contract, which you should obviously refrain from!

Comment: Thank-you Federico and fge for your answers.  Both of which were similar.  After testing the two I felt the ForwardingMap was a slightly better fit.  I +1'ed up both your answers in appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use an `EnumMap` that overwrites the `put()` method:

```
public enum Constants {
    KEY_NAME_1, KEY_NAME_2, KEY_NAME_3;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    public static <T> EnumMap<Constants, Optional<T>> asMap(
        final Constants... validKeys) {

        return new EnumMap<Constants, Optional<T>>(Constants.class) {
            {
                for (Constants c : validKeys) {
                    super.put(c, Optional.absent());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Optional<T> put(Constants key, Optional<T> value) {
                if (!this.containsKey(key)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid key");
                }
                return super.put(key, value);
            }
        };
    }

    public static <T> Map<Constants, Optional<T>> withValues(
        EnumMap<Constants, Optional<T>> map) {

        return Maps.filterValues(map, new Predicate<Optional<T>>() {

            @Override
            public boolean apply(Optional<T> input) {
                return input.isPresent();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is an `enum` with a static method that creates an anonymous `EnumMap` initialized with the provided keys. It uses the anonymous class' initializer block to map the provided keys to `Optional.absent()` and overrides the `put` 
method to disallow putting keys not provided as arguments.

It also has a helper method that returns a view of the map containing the entries that have a value different than `Optional.absent()`.

Sample usage:

```
// Create map with KEY_NAME_1 and KEY_NAME_2 only
EnumMap<Constants, Optional<String>> map = 
    Constants.asMap(Constants.KEY_NAME_1, Constants.KEY_NAME_2);

System.out.println(map); // {KEY_NAME_1=Optional.absent(), KEY_NAME_2=Optional.absent()}

map.put(Constants.KEY_NAME_2, Optional.of("two"));

System.out.println(map); // {KEY_NAME_1=Optional.absent(), KEY_NAME_2=Optional.of(two)}

Map<Constants, Optional<String>> withValues = Constants.withValues(map);

System.out.println(withValues); // {KEY_NAME_2=Optional.of(two)}

map.put(Constants.KEY_NAME_3, Optional.of("three")); // throws IllegalArgumentException
```

// TODO Override `remove()` in returned map so that instead of removing the entry it sets an `Optional.absent()`. Same with other methods that might affect the map.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Guava can do that for you. Guava defines `ImmutableMap` which means neither the keys nor the values can be modified. What you are describing is more like a static array than a map, where the array positions map to fixed keys. You might be better off writing your own `Map` implementation. You could store an `ImmutableMap<Key,Integer>` for the keys, where the values are the positions in an array of the actual map values, say `Value[]`, initialized with the size of the set of keys. Then you can implement your custom `put` that throws an exception if the provided key is not in the `ImmutableMap`.

Or you can just define a wrapper for some `Map` implementation that implements `put`.